# Amazon S3 TransferListener never gets called

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having an issue with an Android application I am writing.  We are storing some photos in our Amazon S3 bucket, and when I try to access them from the app, the callbacks in my TransferListener never get called.

```
// S3Networker.java singleton
static final String AWS_COGNITO_POOL_ID = "OUR ID IS HERE";
static final String AWS_BUCKET_NAME = "OUR BUCKET NAME";
TransferUtility transferUtility = null;

private S3Networker instance;

private S3Networker() {
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            Application.getContext(),
            AWS_COGNITO_POOL_ID,
            Regions.US_WEST_2
    );
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client,Application.getContext());
}

public getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new S3Networker();
    }
    return instance;
}

// ...
// Some class methods that don't touch S3
// ...

// S3 Download Method
public void S3PhotoFetch() {
    final String objectKey = "path/to/item.jpg";
    final File fileDownload = new File(Application.getContext().getCacheDir(), objectKey);
    TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.download(
            AWS_PHOTO_BUCKET_NAME,
            objectKey,
            fileDownload );
    transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener(){

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStateChanged: " + state);
            if (TransferState.COMPLETED.equals(state)) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "Download finished");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) { }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError: ", ex);
        }
    });
}
```

The file runs fine, nothing is crashing.  However, the application is never calling the onStateChanged or onError functions in the TransferListener, and I am subsequently never receiving my data from S3.  Can somebody explain why, and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried using the S3 TransferUtility sample on https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples ?

This sample does what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I have used a few sample apps, including the one above.  The issue I'm having is that the callback functions onStateChanged(), onProgressChanged(), and onError() are not being called in this specific application, although they are in other applications.

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml and check whether you are declaring <service
            android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
            android:enabled="true" /> it in <application> tag or not.

Comment: Hi Ravi,

I do have the TransferService in my manifest

Comment: i think, you have not called S3PhotoFetch() function in above code.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE**

**I have created RxJava utils for Upload and Download from s3.**

[RxAWSUploadUtil](https://gist.github.com/UttamPanchasara/7d3e7cfbb5b66bb699e9d0d10e771ce6)

[RxAWSDownloadUtil](https://gist.github.com/UttamPanchasara/601bef60e2efb8a5b26d795d66d18eaa)

Hope this will help you..

---

Hope you have register service in manifest, if you don;t thn please add in Manifest. Make sure your POOL_ID and Region is currect.

I Suggest you to check your poolID and region because mostly problem occurs from there,

Have a look at below code to download files from s3 server. compare with yours.

**dependencies :**

```
//aws
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'
```

Add your S3 Provider to Application Class, don't need to write at every time.

**AppController.class**

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;
    private static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mContext = this;

        credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),    /* get the context for the application */
                "us-east-4658798797987",    /* Identity Pool ID */
                Regions.US_WEST_2           /* Region for your identity pool--US_WEST_2 or EU_WEST_2*/
        );
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredentialProvider() {
        return credentialsProvider;
    }
}
```

**AppController.class & service in Manifest :**

```
<application
    android:name=".AppController"
    .....
    .....>

    <service
        android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
        android:enabled="true" />

</application>
```

Here I have created util to make download call,

```
public class S3DownloadUtil {
    private AmazonS3Client mS3Client;
    private TransferUtility transferUtility;

    public S3DownloadUtil() {

        mS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(AppController.getCredentialProvider());
        transferUtility = new TransferUtility(mS3Client, AppController.getContext());
    }

    //download method
    public void download(final String FILE_KEY, File downloadFile) {
            final TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download(
                    AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,     /* The bucket to download from */
                    FILE_KEY,    /* The key for the object to download */
                    downloadFile        /* The file to download the object to */
            );

            observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                    switch (state) {
                        case COMPLETED: {
                            transferUtility.deleteTransferRecord(id);
                            String resourceUrl = mS3Client.getResourceUrl(observer.getBucket(), FILE_KEY);  // get resourceUrl
                            Log.d(TAG, "onStateChanged: " + state);
                            break;
                        }

                        case CANCELED: {
                            transferUtility.deleteTransferRecord(id);
                            String resourceUrl = mS3Client.getResourceUrl(observer.getBucket(), FILE_KEY);  // get resourceUrl
                            Log.d(TAG, "onStateChanged: " + state);
                            break;
                        }

                        case FAILED: {
                            transferUtility.deleteTransferRecord(id);
                            String resourceUrl = mS3Client.getResourceUrl(observer.getBucket(), FILE_KEY);  // get resourceUrl
                            Log.d(TAG, "onStateChanged: " + state);
                            break;
                        }

                        case PAUSED: {
                            break;
                        }

                        case WAITING_FOR_NETWORK: {
                            transferUtility.deleteTransferRecord(id);
                            String resourceUrl = mS3Client.getResourceUrl(observer.getBucket(), FILE_KEY);  // get resourceUrl
                            Log.d(TAG, "onStateChanged: " + state);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Now just call util to download as below,

```
 String key = "yourKey";
 String storageFilePath = "your_storage_location";
 new S3DownloadUtil().download(key, new File(storageFilePath));
```

Comment: third time implement s3 but I still forget this line in Manifest, thank a lot !

Comment: heppy to help.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I spent a lot of time on searching solution but all solutions aren't good. I mean that you will have an issue with uploading big images also.

So, try to resolve your issue by "MultiPart File Upload" like https://dzone.com/articles/amazon-s3-parallel-multipart

It works for me. It resolves the uploading big images as well.

Comment: You have to write the service in Android manifest.